# Where do i find Test Device iD for AdMob

Tags: ios, unit-testing, admob

Today i signed up with Google's Admob program. To integrate admob's test ads i need a test device iD.

```
 GADRequest *request =[GADRequest request];
 request.testDevice = @"[GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, @"MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID"];
 [self.bannerView loadRequest:request];
```

Where do i get a test device ID? I'm looking around my account with Google's Admob and I can't seem to find any test device iD.

Answer (score 7):

If you build and run your project on Xcode, show below message on console.
You can use that test device id.

```
2015-01-10 09:11:32.593 VineUploader[662:60b] <Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"944537259734b6f30367fad2271a8c6a" ];
```

Comment: So the long number goes inside the @"MY_TEST_DEVICE_ID" or is request.testDevices=@"@"long number"];   separate for device test ads?